# Error message on Azure after upload website onto it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got a page of error message displayed on my Azure mainpage after uploaded a website to Azure through Visual Studio 2015.

http://i60.tinypic.com/2ed8v1e.png

Comment: I would recommend copying the exception information from your site to here in text instead of a picture

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without more information! but my initial thought would be that you have tried to deploy a number of solutions to the same website, and they are interfering with each other.

If you click on settings on the publish dialogue, inside 'File Publish Options' tick 'Remove additional files at destination'

Run that and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't properly configured OWIN, read this [article](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) to fix your OWIN App Startup class,  then redeploy to see if that fixes it